# Cocoa KVC: "class is not key value coding-compliant"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding

I'm trying to update some properties with KVC. The properties have been synthesized.

This line works:

```
myObject.value = intValue;
```

This doesn't work:

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKey:@"myObject.value"];
```

And blows up with:  *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyViewController 0xd1cec0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myObject.value.'*

Yet further up the method (awakeFromNib) other instances of the same class respond fine to setValue:forKey: calls. The only difference is this particular instance was created and wired up in IB.

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myObject.value"] is redundant, it's using a format that doesn't have any arguments. You should probably just use @"myObject.value".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's telling you that isn't a valid key for that object, and indeed it isn't: "myObject.value" is a keypath, not a single key.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot pass a key path as the second argument to `-[NSObject setValue:forKey:]`. You want to use `setValue:forKeyPath:` instead:

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKeyPath:@"myObject.value"];
```

My understanding is that `setValue:forKey:` is provided as a performance optimization. Since it cannot take a key path, it doesn't have to parse the key string.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chuck.

I think you need to do this instead:

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKeyPath:@"myObject.value"];
```

or via each part of the key path like:

```
id myObject = [self objectForKey:@"myObject"];
[myObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKey:@"value"];
```