# what's the difference between single key and keypath?

Tags: objective-c

as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100101/cocoa-kvc-question-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant) page

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue] forKey:@"myObject.value"];
```

The answer was that "of course, it's a key path not a single key", What does that mean?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/BasicPrinciples.html

Comment: thank you, but you should have posted it as answer so i can mark it an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A key is a string that identifies a property of an object. A key *path* is a list of keys separated by dots, used to identify a nested property.

Here's an example. If an object `person` has a property `address`, which itself has a property `town` you could get the town value in two steps using keys:

```
id address = [person valueForKey:@"address"];
id town = [address valueForKey:@"town"];
```

or in one step using a keyPath:

```
id town = [person valueForKeyPath:@"address.town"];
```

Have a look at Apple's docs on [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i) for further details.

Comment: so the key must be the name of a property of the object being stored?
if so then what's the alternative, for example like dictionaries or hashtables in java and C#? where keys could be any string or object?

Comment: @LolaRun Yes, the keys must be the property name. Or in the case of Dictionaries, the key is the key. See example code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20015365/642706) to another question: [Directly accessing nested dictionary values in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317760/directly-accessing-nested-dictionary-values-in-objective-c/20015365#20015365)

Comment: great example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**valueForKey vs valueForKeyPath**

[[Objective-C KVC]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67622702/4770877)
[[Swift KVC]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163865/4770877)

- `valueForKey` is about `KVC`
- `valueForKeyPath` is `KVC` + dot syntax

You are able to use `valueForKeyPath` for root properties, but you are not able to use `valueForKey` for nested properties

```
A has -> B has -> C
```

```
//root properties
B *b1 = [a valueForKey:@"b"];

B *b2 = [a valueForKeyPath:@"b"];

//nested properties
C *c1 = [a valueForKey:@"b.c"]; //[<A 0x6000016c0050> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key b.c. (NSUnknownKeyException)
   
C *c2 = [a valueForKeyPath:@"b.c"];
```

Additional context

```
//access to not existing
[a valueForKey:@"d"]; //runtime error: [<A 0x600003404600> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key d. (NSUnknownKeyException)

//they both return `id` that is why it is simple to work with them
id id1 = [a valueForKey:@"b"];
B *b1 = (B*) id1;//[b1 isKindOfClass:[B class]]
//or
B *b2 = [a valueForKey:@"b"];

//Wrong cast
C *c1 = [a valueForKey:@"b"];
[c1 fooC]; //-[B fooC]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001f48980 (NSInvalidArgumentException)
```