# KVO vs NSNotification vs protocol/delegates?

Tags: iphone, ios, protocols, key-value-observing, nsnotifications

I have some idea of which to use when but the exact usage is still not clear to me. Can someone explain with example?

Comment: Try reading this, it's a really interesting blog article about the subject for a coders point of view. http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use a delegate if you want to talk to only one object. For example, a tableView has a delegate - only one object should be responsible for dealing with it.

Use notifications if you want to tell everyone that something has happened. For example in low memory situations a notification is sent telling your app that there has been a memory warning. Because lots of objects in your app might want to lower their memory usage it's a notification.

I don't think KVO is a good idea at all and try not to use it but, if you want to find out if a property has changed you can listen for changes.

Hope that helps.

PS [This sums up why I think KVO is broken](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html)

Comment: I know this is old, but I still wanna disagree with it :) That article makes excellent points re. why the KVO API is broken, but it also accurately states that it's still a powerful tool. There are lots of situations where it can save a lot of ugly code. Use it with a wrapper like the one he provided if you like, but do use it.

Comment: Use KVO when observers need immediate response. And one can us NSNotifications when the observers can wait for the event loop.

Comment: @MANN I don't think I understand - notifications aren't asynchronous, they are also fired immediately (although you don't get the willChange options you get with KVO)

Comment: @deanWombourne Never said NSNotifications aren't async. Its just the next event loop. Link--https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html --> ...Instead of a central object that broadcasts notifications to all objects that have registered as observers, KVO notifications go directly to observing objects when changes in property values occur.

Comment: @Shinigami may you please outline some simple good examples for KVO?

Comment: KVO is a good idea if you need to move over the code to the Mac and then can take advantage of bindings.

Answer (score 15):

Use a delegate when there is a "master/slave" relationship (delegate knows about the class and class knows about the delegate), with one class higher up the control hierarchy, and when it is clear that there won't be situations where other elements (mostly UI) will be interested in knowing what the class has to say.

Use notifications when the class is not interested in knowing who listens and how many they are, anybody and any number can register for the notifications.

KVO is useful to listen "without the class knowing", although of course that's not the case, the class on which KVO is applied does not need to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Delegation is a design pattern that you use when you want some other object to modify the sender's behavior.  Example: terminal windows avoid showing any lines or characters that are clipped by the window's edges, because the terminal window's delegate alters the size of the window to ensure this.

Notification is a pattern to use when you don't need a response. Example: you get a notification that the system is about to go to sleep.  The sender of that notification doesn't care what you do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Even when all three would serve your need in a situation, delegate would still be a prefer option:

1. Reuseability.
2. Self documented.  By examining the class's header file, one would immediately recognize what / how the data exchanged taking places.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS Delegate pattern, NotificationCenter, KVO**

**Delegate**

`delegate` pattern is a design pattern which can relate to Structural (Decorator or Wrapper pattern by GoF) which adds behaviors and responsibilities to an object without changing its code. Yo can move some logic into another helper class or use it as a skeleton. It is an alternative for Inheritance. Technically it uses `association`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967271/4770877). Kotlin language supports `delegate` pattern on language layer. As for iOS usually it is used for `Loose coupling` for communicate between classes `Class1 <-> Class2` without `Retain cycle`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020491/4770877) where `SomeClass1 -> SomeClass2` and `SomeClass2 weak-> SomeClass1`

```
protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {
    func foo()
}

class SomeClass1: SomeProtocol {
    let someClass2 = SomeClass2()

    init() {
        someClass2.delegate = self
    }
    
    func foo() {
        print("foo is called")
    }
}

class SomeClass2 {
    
    weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?
    
    func onButtonTap() {
        delegate?.foo()
    }
}
```

**NotificationCenter**

`NotificationCenter or NSNotificationCenter(Objective-C)` (not Remote(Push) or Local Notifications) is a kind of `publish/subscribe event bus`. You have `NotificationCenter` singleton object whic is a single point for anybody to send or receive event. You can use it for sending events through the all application and anybody can interrupt it. Such system is fast for developing but hard for supporting. It is also a kind of `Loose coupling` system.

You can use next API of NotificationCenter:

```
post(name: object: userInfo:)
addObserver(_ observer: selector: name: object:)
removeObserver(_ observer: selector: object:)
```

E.g. system's showing, hiding keyboard

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
}
    
@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
}
```

**KVO**

`KVO` - Key-Value Observing. Observing changes on Objective-C supported property value. You can use it when you need to know about some changes on object without any request

**Objective-C** -`@property`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233088/4770877) which uses `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` for `KVO`

*Notes

- If you override `willChangeValueForKey`, `didChangeValueForKey` the `observeValueForKeyPath` is not fired
- If you use iVar[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233088/4770877) setter you are responsible for calling `willChangeValueForKey`, `didChangeValueForKey`

```
#import "SomeClass.h"

@interface SomeClass()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someVariable;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (void) foo 
{    
    [self addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"someVariable" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context: nil];
    
    self.someVariable = @"set someVariable";
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"someVariable"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", change);
    }
}

@end
```

**Swift** - `NSObject` and `@objc dynamic`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60937714/4770877)

```
class SomeClass1 : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var v = 0
}

class SomeClass2 {
    var kvoToken: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    func subscribe(someClass1: SomeClass1) {
        kvoToken = someClass1.observe(\.v, options: .new) { (object, change) in
            guard let value = change.newValue else { return }
            print("New value: \(value)")
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        kvoToken?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

or

```
public class SomeClass: NSObject 
    public override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    }
}

func foo() {
    someClass1.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "v", options: .new, context: nil) //forKeyPath: #keyPath(SomeClass.v)
}
```

[[Objective-C KVC vs KVO]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67622702/4770877)
[[Swift KVC]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163865/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion KVO is better because of it's zero-overhead advantages. 
Notifications has overhead even if you aren't using/observing them. To improve that you can use different NotificationCenters but even with that some overhead will be there (correct me if I'm wrong). KVO is little complex but its worth when you have to observe lots of stuff.

Comment: How much, practically speaking, is the overhead?