# Using NotificationCenter to trigger a UIAlertController on a different view

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uialertcontroller, notificationcenter

I have two ViewControllers (ViewController is the first; SecondViewController is the second) embedded in a Navigation Controller.

**On ViewController**, there is a NotificationCenter observer in viewDidLoad.

**On SecondViewController**, I have a button that should post a notification to ViewController that will trigger a UIAlertController when it appears again.

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addObservers()
    }

    func addObservers(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(alertThankYou), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: Constants.handleThankYouNotif), object: nil)
    }
    func removeObservers(){
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name(rawValue: Constants.handleThankYouNotif), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func alertThankYou(notification: Notification) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "THANK YOU", message: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("done pressed")
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        removeObservers()
    }

}
```

SecondViewController:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // Press this first to post the Notification!
    @IBAction func TRIGGERPOSTPRESSED(_ sender: UIButton) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(Constants.handleThankYouNotif), object: nil)
    }

    // Then press this to return back to ViewController to HOPEFULLY see an Alert.
    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            (appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
    }

}
```

**The problem:**
On `SecondViewController`, when `TRIGGERPOSTPRESSED` is pressed, I get this warning in console:

> Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

**What should happen:**
On `SecondViewController`, when `TRIGGERPOSTPRESSED` is pressed, I should not get any errors. Then when `close` is pressed and the App returns back to `ViewController`, i should get the alert!

**How can I achieve this with NotificationCenter?**

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should not use **NotificationCenter**, in this case, you should use **Delegates Protocol Pattern** 
as in this previous question about [Notification Center vs. Delegation in iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215346/notification-center-vs-delegation-in-ios-sdk)  and of course this not the issue producer but it's the right practice to use Delegation when you need only tow classes to communicate.

Comment: It has to be NotificationCenter. The example I posted is minified; there will be more than 2 VC's communicating. But once I solve the issue presented in my question, I will be able to solve the rest.

Comment: @Joe can't agree with you that it has to be `NotificationCenter`. In most cases (and it looks that here as well), it's an anti-pattern and would bring troubles sooner or later. A lot of articles around describing consequences and possible alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the notification on completion while dismissing the SecondViewController.
The code snippet:

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(handleThankYouNotif), object: nil)
        })
        (appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

[image: The alert pop up]

Comment: While the alert does show, console reports this: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for SecondViewController`

Comment: dismiss with animated: false. I hope you are not presenting secondViewController from viewDidLoad() of firstViewController.