# is KVO still "broken"?

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I let down KVO pattern since I read this :
[KVO vs NSNotification vs protocol/delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864838/kvo-vs-nsnotification-vs-protocol-delegates), where it uses a hard word : "broken", refering to [an interesting article from Mike Ash](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html) relating three API design problem in 2011.

I can't find any news after that year.
How did KVO evolve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Mike Ash says KVO is broken, he isn't talking about if it works or not. Ash is saying that the API is designed badly and this bad design limits what developers can do with it.

A better use of "KVO-esque" programming can be found in libraries like ReactiveCocoa.

If you want to learn more check out these links.

- https://leanpub.com/iosfrp/
- https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

Comment: Yes, I forgot the quotation marks...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the links. This one suits me better : https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html

Comment: A really nice (more modern) library for dealing with KVO is [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController)