# What does the "\" notation do in the following Swift code snippet?

Tags: swift, swift5

This question is based upon the excellent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835826/642697

```
var asciiValues: [UInt8] { compactMap(\.asciiValue) }
```

I'm hoping someone can explain the "\" notation and perhaps point me at the documentation for it as further reading?

The snippet below is how I have seen/used compactMap before.  Are they the same?

```
var asciiValues: [UInt8] { compactMap { $0.asciiValue }}
```

Comment: `KeyPath`: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-2-keypaths-get-a-promotion/

Comment: Thanks for the help both - exactly what i needed.

Comment: Not my vote, but a search for "backslash" in this tag leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543502/swift-what-does-backslash-dot-mean, which is quite close to what you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinR I did try a search on the swift tag, but didn't see that one.  I'm more than happy if people want to vote close as a duplicate of that question