# Traversing NSDictionary in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Is there an easy way for me to pull out a particular value from an NSDictionary, without calling `objectForKey` for each level I want to go down?

For example:

```
{
    response = {
        data = {
            foo = "bar";
        };
        user = {
            "first_name" = "Joe";
            "last_name" = "Bloggs";
        };
    };
}
```

Is there any easy way to pull out `first_name`? In reality, my data is much more nested than this, and I want to pull out data at various different levels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i) is your friend!

Using KVC, you should be able to do something like:

```
NSString * name = [response valueForKeyPath:@"user.first_name"];
```

Here's [another related question with answers that may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317760/directly-accessing-inner-arrays-in-objective-c) which also [points to another question with further elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269568/whats-the-difference-between-single-key-and-keypath/4270220).

Here is the documentation for [`valueForKeyPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKeyPath:).

Answer (score 2):

Use `valueForKeyPath`? It's in Apple's docs.

This is for an array, but should work similarly: [theocacao.com on NSArray and KVC](http://theocacao.com/document.page/165)

Also, make sure you're using strings as the key. You can run into problems.

For reference on Key-Value Coding: [Apple Docs on Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170)